Show Tooltip on hover over label on horizontal bar graph in chart.js
i want to show the tooltip on hover over label
now what happening is when i drag my cursor from bar to label the tooltip remains i want
 type: "bar",
      data: {
        labels: data.labels,
        datasets: data.datasets,
      },
      options: {
        indexAxis: "y",
        animation: {
          duration: 0,
        },
        plugins: {
          legend: {
            display: checked ? true : false,
          },
          tooltip: {
            intersect: true,
            callbacks: {
              label: function (context) {
                const value = context.raw;
                return value;
              },
              title: function (context) {
                const index = context[0].dataIndex;
                return fullLabels[index];
              },
            },
            ...(checked ? { mode: "index", intersect: true } : {}),
          },
        },
        },
      },

i have tried intersection: true in tooltip option but it does not worked for me

Could you share the complete code ?
